# Webpack Babel Arrow Function Module Build Error

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am attempting to run a few arrow functions within my react code, but despite adding babel loaders to build the code in a readable format, I am receiving an error at the `=` portion of my arrow functions.

```
export default class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        ...
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            flash: '',
            suggestions: [],
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
    }
    ...
    onChange = (editorState) => {
        this.setState({
            suggestions: ['test']
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR in ./public/components/app/activity-feed/feed/VerticalTimeline/CommentComponents/CommentForm.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (150:13)
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: "./public/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {   
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

**package.json:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    ....
  }
```

Comment: FYI If you use arrow function syntax, you can't bind them to an object. Remove the `this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);` in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed the bind, but still receiving the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what's your babel configuration look like? .babelrc, package.json, wherever you're keeping it

Comment: `{ 
    presets: [ "es2015", "react" ] 
}`, which is located in `.babelrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to define class properties using the equal sign. This is still a proposal so it will not work out of the box using babel. What you need is a plugin.

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

```
//.babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

A cool feature of this proposal is that it creates bounded functions. So there is no need to use `.bind` in constructor anymore! You can read more about it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties).